# Giving Typescript classes access to React hooks state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to make a game using React to display the UI elements and using Typescript classes to represent the state of the game.

Here are a few examples of the classes I'm using to represent my data:

```
export class Place extends Entity {
  items: Item[];
  npcs: NPC[];
  location: LatLng | null;
  onEnter: (...args: any[]) => any = () => {};
  constructor(
    name: string,
    description: string,
    location?: LatLng,
    onEnter: (...args: any[]) => any = () => {},
    items: Item[] = [],
    npcs: NPC[] = []
  ) {
    super(name, description);
    this.items = items;
    this.npcs = npcs;
    this.location = location ? location : null;
    this.onEnter = onEnter;
  }


export class Item extends Entity {
  url: string;
  constructor(
    name: string,
    description: string,
    actions = {},
    url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/46/Question_mark_%28black%29.svg/1920px-Question_mark_%28black%29.svg.png"
  ) {
    super(name, description);
    this.url = url;
    this.actions = actions;
  }
}

export class NPC {
  name: string;
  description: string;
  messages: Message[];
  url: string;
  timesTalkedTo = 0;
  constructor(
    name: string,
    description: string,
    url = "https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1378/PNG/512/avatardefault_92824.png",
    messages: Message[] = []
  ) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.messages = messages;
    this.url = url;
  }

  getMsg() {
    console.log(this.messages);
    if (this.messages.length > 1) {
      for (var i = 1; i < this.messages.length; i++) {
        const msg = this.messages[i];
        if (msg["cond"] && msg["cond"]()) {
          this.timesTalkedTo += 1;
          return msg;
        }
      }
    }
    this.timesTalkedTo += 1;
    return this.messages[0];
  }
}
```

Later on, I store instances of these classes in hooks so I can display them using other components I've defined:

```
function UI() {
  const [places, setPlaces] = useState({});
  const [inventory, setInventory] = useState([]);
  const [playerPlace, setPlayerPlace] = useState(outside);
  const [playerLocation, setPlayerLocation] = useState(L.latLng([0, 0]));
  ...
```

My problem is that I wanted to define a class and functions like this inside my UI component, so I would be able to access the setState hooks and use the "drop" and "pick up" actions on any item I've defined as Droppable:

```
  class Droppable extends Item {
    dropped;
    constructor(
      name,
      description,
      actions = {},
      dropped = true,
      url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/46/Question_mark_%28black%29.svg/1920px-Question_mark_%28black%29.svg.png"
    ) {
      super(name, description, actions, url);
      this.dropped = dropped;
      const drop = () => {
        addToPlace(removeFromInventory(this));
        this.dropped = true;
        this.actions["pick up"] = pickUp;
        delete this.actions["drop"];
      };
      const pickUp = () => {
        addToInventory(removeFromPlace(this));
        this.dropped = false;
        this.actions["drop"] = drop;
        delete this.actions["pick up"];
      };
      if (dropped) {
        this.actions["pick up"] = pickUp;
      } else {
        this.actions["drop"] = drop;
      }
    }
  }

  const addToInventory = useCallback(
    (item) => {
      setInventory((inv) => [...inv, item]);
      return item;
    },
    [setInventory]
  );
  const removeFromInventory = useCallback(
    (item) => {
      setInventory((inv) => inv.filter((i) => i !== item));
      return item;
    },
    [setInventory]
  );

  const addToPlace = useCallback(
    (item) => {
      setPlaces((places) => {
        return {
          ...places,
          [playerPlace.name]: {
            ...playerPlace,
            items: [...playerPlace.items, item],
          },
        };
      });
      return item;
    },
    [setPlaces, playerPlace]
  );

  const removeFromPlace = useCallback(
    (item) => {
      setPlaces((places) => {
        const newPlace = { ...places[playerPlace.name] };
        newPlace.items = newPlace.items.filter((i) => i !== item);
        const newPlaces = [...places];
        newPlaces[playerPlace.name] = newPlace;
        return newPlaces;
      });
      return item;
    },
    [setPlaces, playerPlace]
  );
```

However, when I try removing an item from the place it's in and adding it to the player's inventory (the "pick up" action), I find that, while it is successfully added to the inventory, it cannot be removed from the place, because the `playerPlace` state variable is stale. Even though `setPlayerPlace` had been called successfully and set the `playerPlace` to a place containing items, the value is still set to its initial empty Place, so there is an error when trying to access the items of that Place.

My guess is that these callbacks are not being updated properly according to the state because they are used inside the class that I defined, but I can't think of any other way to give methods inside the class easy access to the state variables.

Is it a bad idea to be using ordinary classes alongside React in this way? If so, what would be a better way to structure my app. If not, how can I give my classes access to the state inside my React components?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend moving the class outside of the component and then passing the setters and data to the class as parameters if you really want to use classes. You can also use a third-party state management library for this and then hook it together, but I don't think it's really worth it. Generally speaking, using classes for your state in react is an antipattern IMHO. Usually what I would do is just write types and then utility functions for those types if I need to encapsulate functionality. This has many benefits aside from working with react such as easily being able to serialize the data to `JSON` (they are now POJOs).